# Supplementary variables in ggbiplot PCA

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

I am trying to draw PCA results with ggbiplot, how can I draw supplementary variables ?
I found [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603952/multiple-correspondence-analysis-in-r-plotting-supplementary-categorical-variab) for MCA results, but I would like to have the arrows as well...

```
 data(wine)
 wine.pca <- PCA(wine, scale. = TRUE, quanti.sup = c(4,5))
 plot(wine.pca)
 ggbiplot(wine.pca)
```

[image: With plot.PCA]
[image: With gbiplot]

Besides, this code gives me an error :

```
 1: In sweep(pcobj$ind$coord, 2, 1/(d * nobs.factor), FUN = "*") :
    STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]'
 2: In sweep(v, 2, d^var.scale, FUN = "*") :
    STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and didn't reproduce your error but had other problems. I googled `PCA()` and found the package used to do the PCA was `FactoMineR`. After looking at the documentation, I also changed `scale.` to `scale.unit` and `quanti.sup` to `quali.sup`, giving the correct columns the categorical variables are in.

```
library(FactoMineR)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- PCA(wine, scale.unit = TRUE, quali.sup = c(1,2))
plot(wine.pca)
ggbiplot(wine.pca)
```

That should give the correct output.

[image]